# How to deserialize a serialized C# binary file in Python?

Tags: c#, python, serialization, deserialization, python.net

I want to deserialize a binary file that's made in C# in Visual Studio 2017.

One program(C#) serializes `structs` of different types of `arrays` and the other program(C#) deserializes the file. I wonder how to do the same job in Python.

```
// ClassTickStruct.dll
namespace ClassTickStruct
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct struct_tick
    {
        public uint[] arr_currentIndex;
        public string[] arr_currentType;
        public DateTime[] arr_currentTime;
 
        public struct_tick(byte size_index, byte size_type, byte size_time)
        {
            arr_currentIndex = new uint[size_index];
            arr_currentType = new string[size_type];
            arr_currentTime = new DateTime[size_time];
        }
    }
}
```

```
// How one program(C#) serializes structs
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file.bin, FileMode.Append))
{
    var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    bFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, obj_struct);
}
```

```
// How the other program(C#) deserializes the file
List<struct_tick> list_read = new List<struct_tick>();
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    //bFormatter.Binder = new AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder();

    while (fileStream.Position != fileStream.Length)
    {
        list_read.Add((struct_tick)bFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream));
    }
}
```

I referred to [Is there a way to read C# serialized objects into Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251765/is-there-a-way-to-read-c-sharp-serialized-objects-into-python) and tried DirtyLittleHelper's code, but an error occurs that says:

```
    data = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'tickReceiver, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Assembly can't be found
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   location: System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
```

I had the same `Assembly can't be found` error when the C# programs didn't share the dll of the struct. Then I just made a class library(dll) with the structure in it and made the programs refer to it and they worked without the error.

```
# the whole Python code to deserialize the file
import clr
import System
#requires pythonnet installed -> pip install pythonnet 
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\null\Desktop\RECEIVER\ClassTickStruct.dll")

from System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary import BinaryFormatter
from System.IO import FileStream,FileMode,FileAccess,FileShare

filepath = "file.bin"
serializer = BinaryFormatter()
reader = FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
data = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
```

I think what's different is that it's `(struct_tick)bFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream)` in C# and it's just `serializer.Deserialize(reader)` in Python. Maybe it needs some job with the struct in the dll?

Comment: hi @maynull, why dont you serialize with "common format" instead of relying on C# `[Serializable]` attribute? json, xml, or fancy protobuf might help.

Comment: I think you'll be much better off using a language/framework-agnostic serialization format like XML or JSON or something like that. Getting things right in binary is a much much more complicated job than using a XML or JSON lib for data exchange.

Comment: When working with different frameworks it's better to use common formats like XML/JSon etc... or you can implement your own binary format if performance is an issue. Using BinaryFormatter is not a very good idea because you don't have control over it.

Comment: If you want binary serialization that is easy to use between different programming languages, you should look at [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers).

Comment: @Bagus Tesa Thank you for your recommendation. The reason I prefer this way is that it's possible to ```append``` new structs of arrays to ```the same one local file``` over and over ```without reading the file``` and it's more efficient in terms of performance(as I know of). I looked at JSON, google protobuf and etc, but I couldn't find any documents or usages that deal with those options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I want to do is actually possible with protobuf.

```
// WRITE
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Append))
{
    Serializer.Serialize(fileStream, OBJ_struct);
}

// READ
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    struct_obj str = Serializer.Deserialize<struct_obj >(fileStream);

    for (int num=0;  num < str.arr_currentIndex.Length; num++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(str.arr_currentIndex[num]);
    }

}
```

Thank you those who recommended protobuf!